# How to detect which element is on the center of the screen with scroll position?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, position, offset

I want to detect which element is visible on the screen when scrolling down/up.
I have to set as active menu item on the menu which targets that element.

```
// must have a page class
$('.page').each(function(){
    $positionData[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).offset().top;
});

$(document).scroll(function(){
    var $position = $(this).scrollTop();
    if($position > $height && !$body.hasClass('scrolled')) {
        $body.addClass('scrolled');

        //detech the scroll is between an element offset
    } else if($position < $height) {
        $body.removeClass('scrolled');
    }
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) users;

There is a component already can be found named Scrollspy.

[Scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

How to use?

1: Add relative positioning to body.

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
```

2: Add data-spy="scroll" and data-target="" attributes to your body. (data-target must target your menu)

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example">
```

3: Set your menu. Don't for get to add nav class to your ul/ol element.

```
<div id="navbar-example">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#project">PROJECT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

4: Check your target elements to every element must have an id attribute same as your link targets.

```
<div id="home"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the problem this creates the ability to scroll to elements centering them in the screen. The OP wanted an event to say hey I am in the middle of the screen now..do something..the event must exist (with scrollspy) as when you scroll the menu is updated for scrollspy ..but I can find NO docs on it..

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery plugin [inview](https://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin) ([github](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview)) to do that.

```
$('.scrollWatch').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible) {
        // do something here
        $(this).addClass('scrolled');
        $(this).text('mom! I\'m here.');
    } else {
        // do something here with invisible
        $(this).removeClass('scrolled');
        $(this).text('1');
    }
});
```

I created a demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssk7833/uqyp66en/1/) for you, please use DevTools to see what changes in HTML.

Comment: thank you. i found a solution close to your answer. bootstrap already has a component. scrollspy.

Comment: Can you post your solution?